# Adding or updating (big) array values in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP and SQL queries but learning quick and still enjoying it as well!
Currently I'm working on a web app where I have an array of ±1700 values which i want to store in  a database. I've managed to get it working with just adding them (see code below) but the thing is, they need to be updated as well. The values can change and new ones will be added. 
It's a php script that will run as a cron job to keep the database updated.

I know that I have to do something with '...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...' but I don't know how to implement it in my SQL query.

This is my code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
));

$sql = 'INSERT INTO advertisers_tbl (advertisers_id, advertisers_name) VALUES ';
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();

foreach ($advertisers as $row) {
    $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
    $insertData[] = $row['id'];
    $insertData[] = $row['name'];
}

if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
    $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you serialize the advertisers array and save it as a string. While when you need to update just unserialize it and add elements in it.

Comment: Have you tried the query? What problems are you encountering?

Comment: That looks like good code for a 'batched insert'.  It should be possible to build a IODKU statement similarly.  For help there, please explain what "update" is needed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The problem is that I have no idea what the query should be. SQL queries are still very new to me and having a tough time grasping them when they get slightly complicated.

Comment: But had you tried @Levi you would have encountered a problem from which you could've learned, rather than just having someone provide the code for you. SO is slightly different than Yoda in that respect, "Try, there is no not try."

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple what you are seeking. First of all you must be sure you have a unique index (I believe it's `advertisers_id`).

Second, you need a query like:

```
INSERT INTO advertisers_tbl (advertisers_id, advertisers_name) 
VALUES (a_id1, a_n1), (a_id2, a_n2) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
advertisers_id=VALUES(advertisers_id), 
advertisers_name=VALUES(advertisers_name)
```

Comment: There is no need to update fields that are not changing.  Perhaps you meant to say `advertisers_name = VALUES(advertisers_name)`?  That says that the new value comes from the input list.